# Shorten a text that is too long (with sed?)

Tags: sed, characters

I have the following example of a .csv-file

```
"0a","1a","Short text","abc"
"0b","1bx","Here is a very long text","def"
"0c","1cx","Short text again","ghij"
```

And now I want to have a maximum of 16 characters in the 3rd column.
So "Short text" and "Short text again" would be ok.. but "Here is a very long text" should be "Here is a very l". Even better would be "Here is a very l..."

So that text (of the 3rd column) that is too long is shortened and replaced by '...' at the end.

I found this:

```
sed '/^.\{0,16\}$/!d'
```

But this is not really what I am looking for because it extracts only the whole lines with 0-16 characters.

Maybe you have a better idea?

Comment: Notes: (1)`Here is a very l` is indeed 16 characters long, but `Here is a very l...` is 19. Your "even better would be" kinda contradicts "a maximum of 16 characters". (2) I think in csv spaces outside quotes in a field are not formally allowed. The leading spaces thus may be problematic and cause data to be interpreted not in the way you want. Do you mean `"0b","1bx","Here is a very long text","def"`? or are the spaces really there? or a tab? If something is there, should it be kept?

Comment: Yeah, sorry! The leading spaces are only there for clarity. In the csv file there are no leading spaces.

Yes, I mean that the text will be limited to 16 characters and the rest of the text will be replaced with "...".

Answer (score 0):

A better idea – use an actual CSV parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
import sys

rd = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
wr = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

for row in rd:
    if len(row[2]) > 16:
        row[2] = row[2][:15] + "…"
    wr.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is to truncate a text, not to shorten it.
**Assuming** *you want the output to be 3rd column only (with max-lenght 16 char)*
In this case you can use [cut](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) command *(n=16)*:

**Example**

```
cut -c -16
```

To extract 3rd column you can also use `cut` command

**Example**

```
cut -d , -f 3
```

-d is to specify a delimiter
-f is to pick which field
or you can use `"` as delimiter to get extract text without double-quotes

```
cut -d \" -f 6
```

combining them with a [pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) would do the trick

```
cut -d \" -f 6 file.csv | cut -c -16
```

---

**Assuming** *you want to output the whole .csv-file (with 3rd column modified)*
[Kees Trommel's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1701441/1014506) or using a scripting language like `Python` would be an easier approach

Answer (score 0):

Not in sed, but in perl.

You may prefix your substitue by a check, in a perl oneliner, to apply a substitute *only* if the string is longer than the requested size.
Here, in a one way catch, the limit not to be catched, is 13+3 chars.

In a second step, if the match is positive, replace the whole string by the 13 chars + 3 dots.

```bsh
$ echo "12345678901234567" |perl -pe 'if (/^(.{13}).{4}/) { $_="$1..." }'
1234567890123...
$ echo "1234567890123456" |perl -pe 'if (/^(.{13}).{4}/) { $_="$1..." }'
1234567890123456
```

Obviously, sed is not as complex as it may look, and with the same logic but with two catches:
1/ check if the string is longer than 16 chars
2/ if so, replace by the first 13 chars and 3 dots.

```bsh
echo "12345678901234567" |sed '/^.\{16\}./ s/^\(.\{13\}\).\+/\1.../'
1234567890123...
echo "1234567890123456" |sed '/^.\{16\}./ s/^\(.\{13\}\).\+/\1.../'
1234567890123456
```

In a real pseudo-language to enlighten the regular expression:

```perl
if /^.{16}./
{
  s/^(.{13}).+/\1.../
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^\(".*",".*",".\{0,16\}\).*\(",.*\)$/\1\2/'
```

`".*",".*",` first 2 CVS fields

`".\{0,16\}` opening double quote and up to the first 16 characters of the 3rd CVS field

`.*` 16th till the end characters

`",.*\` closing double quote of the 3rd CVS field and remaining CVS fields

`\1` first group: `\(".*",".*",".\{0,16\}\)`

`\2` second group: `\(",.*\)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `sed -re 's/^(".*",".*",".{0,16}).*(",.*)$/\1\2/'` - slightly easier on the eyes